# selected index event is not working in dropdown

Tags: asp.net, ajax

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTime" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" 
                                        AutoPostBack="true" 
                                        onselectedindexchanged="ddlTime_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem  Selected Value = "True">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>8.50</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>9.00</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>9.50</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I have  drop down  with the  event changing .    but  when   ever i select an  value this  event is not  firing at all

```
protected void ddlTime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

What  is the  issue that is  causing  here
    any help  would  be  great
  thank  you

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1099463.aspx

Answer (score 0):

set `CausesValidation="false"`, there are some other validation works when you change selection from dropdown

but
if you want to use validation for dropdown, use `validationGroup` that only dropdown related validation only work